# How to create a server instance of just ComputerName instead of ComputerName\SQLEXPRESS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-express, instance

I'm currently hosting a database on the server `MyComputerName` using SQL Server Express 2014.

I want to move the database to another computer, so I installed SQL Server Express 2014 on it but that computer only has the instance `ThatComputerName\SQLEXPRESS`. When I try to connect to just `ThatComputerName` it throws the error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

However, I can't enable remote connections on `ThatComputerName` because I can't even connect to that instance.

I don't remember what I did on the previous computer to allow me to connect both to `MyComputerName` and `MyComputerName\SQLEXPRESS`, how can I create that instance on the new computer? Do I have to reinstall?

Comment: Hold on. Am looking up something. The default instance name for SQL Server Express is `SQLExpress`, so you installed it correctly. Chances are you did not set up the protocols it is listening on correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't enable remote connections because I can't even connect to that instance"? You need to remote desktop to that other machine, enable TCP/IP, and then connect remotely. Or are you saying that while remoted desktopped into `ThatComputerName` you are not able to connect to the SQL Express instance? Something doesn't add up here.

Comment: I've enabled TCP/IP and turned off firewall. But to enable remote connections, I need to connect to the ThatComputerName and change the properties in SSMS, but I can't connect to the instance in the first place *on* the machine that I want to host the DB.

Comment: please see my answer. You don't need to do anything in SSMS. You just need to restart the service, assuming you enabled TCP/IP for the "instance" and not just for "Native Client".

Comment: I am still confused by "but I can't connect to the instance in the first place on the machine that I want to host the DB". Do you mean that you are physical on `ThatComputerName` via Remote Desktop, AND while on there, you cannot access the local instance of SQLEXRESS? You can't even run `SQLCMD -Q "SELECT @@SERVERNAME;"` from a command line? If _that_ is the case, are you sure that the service is for that instance has been started?

Comment: @srutzky I've editted the description to try to make it clearer. I'm not remote desktoping into either computer. I have two computers side-by-side, and on one of them I can connect to both the `.` and `.\SQLEXPRESS` instance. On the other, I can only connect to the `.\SQLEXPRESS` instance. Both of them have TCP/IP enabled and firewall disabled, but that's not really relevant because I'm not dealing with external connections here.

Comment: Ok. Getting clearer. When you say that you can connect to "both" instances, these are still the same instance, correct? `.` and `.\SQLEXPRESS` are just two different notations that get you to the same instance?

Comment: No, that's not true. I have distinctly different databases in those two different instances, [see here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8fKCf.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot change the *Instance Name* after it has been installed.  But you can uninstall that SQL Server instance and reinstall as a DEFAULT instance.  Ideally you should make a backup of the server, then restore the backups to the new server.

*You can technically detach databases and attach again after the reinstall, but that includes the risk of losing your detached databases. See Aaron Bertrand's post:*

https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-file-backups/

When installing a default instance of SQL Server Express at the **Instance Configuration** page, you must choose the Named Instance radio button **and** type in the default instance name of **MSSQLSERVER**.

All default instances use the **MSSQLSERVER** internally, but they just do not make it visible to you.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting, however, I don't ever remember doing that on my original computer. Oh well, thanks for your help!

Comment: Or back them up and restore them (I talk about why [detach/attach is so dangerous as a backup mechanism here](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-file-backups/)).

Comment: @crclayton This is not true. SQL Server Express uses `SQLExpress` as the default instance name, not `MSSQLSERVER` like all of the other editions do. So you did install it correctly.

Comment: @srutzky - crclayton wanted his database to show **ComputerName** instead of **ComputerName\SQLEXPRESS**.  That is how I set up SQL Server Express a few years ago to be a 'local instance' and not SQLEXPRESS.  Has that behavior changed?

Comment: This answer was correct. I didn't realize it was just hiding the MSSQLSERVER instance label. That makes some other links make sense too. I didn't have to uninstall, but just installed another instance over top of it.

Comment: @RLF I am still investigating. The documentation is very clear that `SQLEXPRESS` is the _default_ instance name, but I am also seeing that it doesn't respond on just the machine name when doing that. So if using an instance name of `MSSQLSERVER` does allow for that, then this answer should be edited since it currently says that `MSSQLSERVER` is always the _default_ instance name but for Express that is not true. In this case you _can't_ use the default instance name. I also recall reading a while ago a reason to not use `MSSQLSERVER` as instance name for Express, but can't find it now.

Comment: @srutzky the instance name that Express Edition setup suggests *by default* is not the same concept as a *default instance*. `\SQLEXPRESS` is absolutely a named instance, not a default instance. It just happens to be the instance name SQL Server uses *by default* when installing an instance of Express. Even with Express you can override that and create a *default instance*, and in this case the "instance name" for the default instance - though that's not really what it is, just how it shows in Configuration Manager and other surfaces - will be just like any other edition (`MSSQLSERVER`).

Comment: @AaronBertrand That's what I was thinking before reading this, [Instance Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143531.aspx), which states: "For SQL Server Express, if you specify SQLExpress for the instance name, a default instance will be created." That is clearly not saying _by default_, but it seems it is also clearly wrong ;-). And the behavior I am seeing supports what you and RLF are saying, and this page even uses `SQLEXPRESS` as an example of a named instance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188642.aspx . So I deleted my answer and +1 to this one :).

Comment: @srutzky I think that's a translation error of some kind. I've asked for the page to be corrected.